# with(nolock) , (nolock) , nolock differences?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, nolock

**I know `with(nolock)` and `(nolock)` are the same or almost the same.** [**REF:with(nolock) or (nolock) - Is there a difference?**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12112855/352101)

but how about `nolock`? You can use either of them in `select` and the only notable difference I can see is when using alias that you can write:

`select * from table1 as mytable with(nolock)`

or

`select * from table1 as mytable (nolock)`

but you can't write:

`select * from table1 as mytable nolock`

**PS**: I'm not discussing `nolock` is good or bad here :)

Comment: See [Table Hints](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx) on MSDN - the behavior is documented.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [with(nolock) or (nolock) - Is there a difference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12112855/withnolock-or-nolock-is-there-a-difference)

Comment: @Bharaththeorare, did you read my question? And the answer below?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The difference is that you *should* be using the syntax `WITH (NOLOCK)` (or `WITH (<any table hint>)`). Why?

1. Without `WITH` is deprecated. From [Table Hints on MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx):

   > Omitting the WITH keyword is a deprecated feature: This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature.
2. `from table1 nolock` does not apply a hint at all - that's an alias. For example:

   ```
   SELECT nolock.name FROM sys.objects nolock ORDER BY nolock.name;
   ```

   Notice that I can use `nolock` as an alias. No hint is applied here.
3. `from table1 as mytable nolock` is invalid syntax in modern versions of SQL Server.

   > Msg 1018, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
   >   Incorrect syntax near 'nolock'. If this is intended as a part of a table hint, A WITH keyword and parenthesis are now required. See SQL Server Books Online for proper syntax.

You should also consider using the session-level hint, `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED`, because then you don't have the syntax issue above, and you also don't have 15 `WITH (NOLOCK)`s littering your query. These make it harder to replace with a different isolation level later (like RCSI, which is far more practical than `READ UNCOMMITTED` IMHO), whereas the single batch-level statement is a very easy one-liner to replace.

Also, and this is for other readers more so than for the OP, please be absolutely sure you understand the risks of using `NOLOCK`, which include getting corrupted data in a single row *that never existed*:

- [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/)
- [The Read Uncommitted Isolation Level (Paul White)](http://sqlperformance.com/2015/04/t-sql-queries/the-read-uncommitted-isolation-level)

Comment: Thanks for the alias stuffs... it took me ages to understand why my nolock is taking ages to return...

Answer (score 1):

The table hint part of the select query has the following syntax:

```
WITH  ( <table_hint> [ [, ]...n ] )
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx